# Get Column Name in Dataset

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have two Dataset and I want to compare two column name.How can I reach column name in a Dataset? What should I write instead of X?

```
for (int j=0;j<=rowCount;j++)
{   
    if (Mysql[i].Tables[i].Rows[j].**X**== Firebird[i].Tables[i].Rows[j].**X**)
    {
        SourceMysql.Add(Mysql[i].Tables[i].Rows[j]);
        DestinationFirebird.Add(Firebird[i].Tables[i].Rows[j]);
    }
    {
        DestinationMysql.Add(Mysql[i].Tables[i].Rows[j]);
        SourceFirebird.Add(Firebird[i].Tables[i].Rows[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. A `DataSet` does NOT have columns, it has a collection of `DataTables`. You may want to clarify what `Mysql` IS as it does not look like a `DataSet` since it is referenced with an index… `Mysql[i]` … ? … Please [edit] your question to clarify what `Mysql` IS along with `SourceMysql`, `DestinationFirebird`, `DestinationMysql` and `SourceFirebird`. This and a description of what the code is doing would also help. I am just saying that it appears that the code is trying to add a row from a `DataTable` to some other collection and this may or may not work.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to compare the data of each row corresponding to the column or just compare the column names.

If you only need to compare column names, you could use code like this: 
Mysql[i].Table[i].Columns[c].ColumnName==Firebird[i].Tables[i].Colums[c].ColumnName       ， 

If there is any problem with my understanding, I hope you can provide more information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.